# Software like graphjam

Tags: flash, graphing

Is there any pre-build software that can build graphs and export as an image like graphjam.com does? (they have a flash application)

Answer (score 0):

http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/ looks like something that could work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've used GraphViz in some of my research to great success. It's very easy to programmically output a `DOT` file for importing and render a fairly attractive image.

Comment: I've used GraphViz and it gives great results, but I suspect the asker should clarify their use case because using GraphViz may not work.